# Passing parameters to AngularJS $timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an ionic mobile application and I need to pass parameters to the $timeout promise so I can make some operations with that parameters.
I read the angularjs doc about $timeout (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) and it says that the last parameter can be parameters passed to the timeout function. I tried this:

```
$timeout(function(params){
    alert(params.p1 + " - " + params.p2);
}, 5000, true, {p1 : "Hello", p2 : "World"});
```

but it is not working, I can't have acces to the params variable inside the timeout function.

Am I doing something wrong? or, is there another way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a new argument that has been [introduced](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) with [angular 1.4.x](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.js). So it could be possible that you are trying to use it with [angular 1.3 or lesser version](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/service/$timeout).

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/c8776Y?p=preview)

Your example should just work provided you are using right version of angular.

```
 $timeout(function(p){
    console.log(p.a);
 },0, true, {a:1, b:2});
```

Another  thing to note is you are not passing this as argument to the timeout promise, they are just arguments passed to the function run by `$timeout` service. If you want to pass the argument as a value resolved by the timeout promise then just return the value.

```
 $timeout(function(p){
    return p; //<-- return it
 },0, true, {a:1, b:2})
 .then(function(value){
     console.log(value)//<-- this is same as p
 });
```

If your real intention is to get the argument passed into the function with version < 1.4, then just move it to a function and invoke it:

```
 function callIt(params){
    return $timeout(function(){ //Return promise if needed
       //Access params here from the outer closure of the function.
     })
 }
```

and just call:

```
callIt({a:1, b:2});
```

Comment: well, I saw that ionic uses v 1.3.6, so I decided to make te function, thanks

Comment: @oware aah probably you are using ionic bundle which comes with 1.3.x

Answer (score 3):

The parameter you're trying to use has been introduced in 1.4 version of angularjs which is currently considered unstable (most likely you're using version <= 1.3 - [$timeout docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/api/ng/service/$timeout)).

You could try:

```
function makeHandler(handler, params) {
  return function() {
    handler(params);
  };
}

$timeout(makeHandler(function(params) {
  alert(params.p1 + " - " + params.p2);
}, {p1 : "Hello", p2 : "World"}), 5000);
```